# Android device cannot play recorded voices

Tags: java, android

I am using below code in order to record voice during calls.

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
recorder.setOutputFile(filepath);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

Calls records successfully , but default media players of device cannot play this files, when i using third party players, they can play recorded files, what is the problem?

Comment: what is the file format in which you are saving the recorded file?

Comment: so maybe the default media player doesn't support 3gp. Did you check the supported media types of the default player?

Comment: It is support, because default voice recorder of device record with 3gp format, i think it is released to bitrate or something like this